# sqldatareader which must be closed error but it has not been used?

Tags: vb.net

All,

This is my code:

```
Public Class frmFindRoute
    Private Sub frmFindRoute_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim cmdroad As SqlCommand
        Dim sdrroad As SqlDataReader

        cmdroad = conRouteMapping.CreateCommand
        cmdroad.CommandText = "Select title, uniqueref from road order by title"

        sdrroad = cmdroad.ExecuteReader
        PopulateListviewHeaders(lvwFromRoad, 1, sdrroad)
        PopulateListview(lvwFromRoad, sdrroad)
        sdrroad = cmdroad.ExecuteReader
        PopulateListviewHeaders(lvwToRoad, 1, sdrroad)
        PopulateListview(lvwToRoad, sdrroad)
        sdrroad.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmbFind_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbFind.Click
        Dim cmdLanes As SqlCommand
        Dim sdrLanes As SqlDataReader

        cmdLanes = conRouteMapping.CreateCommand
        cmdLanes.CommandText = "Select direction, number,uniqueref from lane where roadref='" & lvwFromRoad.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text & "'"
        sdrLanes = cmdLanes.ExecuteReader
        sdrLanes.Read()

        FindRoute(sdrLanes.GetValue(2))
    End Sub

    Private Sub FindRoute(ByVal LaneRef As Guid)
        Dim cmdDestRoad As SqlCommand
        Dim sdrDestRoad As SqlDataReader
        Dim cmdNextJunction As SqlCommand
        Dim sdrNextJunction As SqlDataReader

        cmdDestRoad = conRouteMapping.CreateCommand
        cmdDestRoad.CommandText = "Select roadref from lane where uniqueref='" & LaneRef.ToString & "'"
        sdrDestRoad = cmdDestRoad.ExecuteReader ' << error here
        If sdrDestRoad.GetValue(0) <> lvwToRoad.SelectedItems(1).SubItems(0).Text Then
            cmdNextJunction = conRouteMapping.CreateCommand
            cmdNextJunction.CommandText = "Select tolane from junction where fromlane='" & LaneRef.ToString & "'"
            sdrNextJunction = cmdNextJunction.ExecuteReader
            Do While sdrNextJunction.Read
                'FindRoute(sdrNextJunction.GetValue(0))
            Loop
            sdrNextJunction.Close()
        End If
        sdrDestRoad.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Where I've marked "error here" I get the error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed.

I don't know why? I've already verified that cmdDestRoad and sdrNextJunction aren't used anywhere else in the solution. The data readers in form_load and find_click work fine.

I've also used breakpoints to confirm that it fails the first time it runs this section of code.

Comment: Multiple missing Close calls.  Do practice using the `Using` statement.

Comment: .ExecuteReader returns a reader. You can't have a new reader (a second call to .ExecuteReader) on a single connection without closing the first reader.

Comment: Hans: Thanks for your advice. This is my first vb.net/SQL project, I'm moving from VB6. Mary: So it's the connection that can't have two open readers and not the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mary's answer was correct. You can not have two open readers on a connection. I can't accept it as answer as it's a comment.

The line

```
sdrDestRoad = cmdDestRoad.ExecuteReader
```

Fails because a reader is already opened with the following line in cmbFind_Click:

```
sdrLanes = cmdLanes.ExecuteReader
```

The lines:

```
cmdDestRoad = conRouteMapping.CreateCommand
        cmdDestRoad.CommandText = "Select roadref from lane where uniqueref='" & LaneRef.ToString & "'"
```

are not part of the problem. Opening a second command on the connection didn't cause the error. Trying to open a second reader did.